# How to remove error in copyOf method in java?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am getting error in copyOf method . Can anyone tell where am i wrong ? I am gettingerror

Error Logs :

```
The method `copyOf(U[], int, Class<? extends T[]>)` in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (Object[], int, Class<String>)
    Can only iterate over an array or an instance of `java.lang.Iterable`
```

Code :

```
public class createdevice {
static List<String> Mylist = new ArrayList<String>(); 

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("/home/madhu/Desktop/demo.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String st = sc.nextLine();
        Mylist.add(st);
    }
    Object[] obj = Mylist.toArray();
    String[] str = Arrays.copyOf(obj,obj.length,String.class);  
    for(int i : str.length) {
        System.out.println("String is "+str[i]);
        
    }
    
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        
}

}
```

Comment: The third parameter of copyOf is the type of the copy, not the type of the array element. So it must be an array type.

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter of `Arrays.copyOf` requires to be an array. To solve your issue, simply add `[]`

```java
String[] str = Arrays.copyOf(obj, 2, String[].class);
```